# Only remove entirely empty rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have this data frame:

```
d = {'col1': [1, np.nan, np.nan], 'col2': [1, np.nan, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    col1    col2
0   1.0     1.0
1   NaN     NaN
2   NaN     1.0
```

and want to drop only rows that are empty to produce the following:

```
d = {'col1': [1, np.nan], 'col2': [1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    col1    col2
0   1.0     1
1   NaN     1
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: note that `df.dropna(how='all')` will not convert `col2` to int. You may have to explicitly do it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) page

```
df.dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: df=df.dropna(how='all')